# How to recover icloud account?

Tags: macbook-pro, icloud

I have just bought a Macbook pro. When I install it, I click login to icloud but I forgot question that I use and I don't use email to backup.

I can't speak english good.
Please help me recover icloud question for that case

Comment: start at https://iforgot.apple.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, [iforgot.apple.com](http://iforgot.apple.com). It's also available in your language. As this probably leaves you with nothing seeing as you forgot both email and security questions, your second best shot is [Apple Support](https://getsupport.apple.com/), which is also available for your country. Try to get on the phone with one of their advisors.